# How to force errorbars to render last with Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying over-plot some empirical data with error bars on top of my modelled data.  The error bars seem to be rendering first and are consequently getting over written (see below)

I have tried using zorder but I still get the same result.  The code I am using is

```
    for i in range(1,len(pf)):
            pf[i,:] = av_pf_scale * pf[i,:]
            pylab.semilogy(pf[0,0:180],pf[i,0:180],color='0.75')

    pylab.semilogy(av_pf[0:180],color='r')
    pylab.semilogy(av_mie[0:180],color='g', linestyle='-')

    pylab.draw()
    f = pylab.errorbar(ang,data[j],
                            yerr = delta_data[j],
                            fmt = 'o',
                            markersize = 3,
                            color = 'b',
                            zorder = 300,
                            antialiased = True)
```

I would appreciate if anyone can tell me how to make the errorbars render on top.

[image: Mulitplot]

Comment: Could you provide a clearer example? I'm looking hard at your plot and I can see blue error line bars above the other data (they are above the grey mess and the red and green lines). The values seem to be relatively small and so don't have visible verticals, but that's in the data not matplotlib.

Comment: Have you tried increasing the zorder beyond 300? Also it's odd that the ends of the errorbars are being rendered above the gray lines, but not the lines. (also watch for negative lower error bounds on your first and last data points.)

Comment: alternatively, try setting the zorder of the gray lines to be `-100`.

Comment: +1 Good question!  In the future, it is better to give examples of your problem that other people can run without needing access to your data (see my examples in my answer) http://sscce.org/ .

Comment: Thanks, that is good advice.  In the future I will do.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This looks like it is a bug in `matplotlib` where the `zorder` argument of the `errorbar` is not correctly passed to the vertical lines part of error bars.

replicates your problem :

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.gca()
[ax.plot(rand(50),color='0.75') for j in range(122)];
ax.errorbar(range(50),rand(50),yerr=.3*rand(50))
plt.draw()
```

[image: error bar fail]
Hacky work around:

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.gca()
[ax.plot(rand(50),color='0.75',zorder=-32) for j in range(122)];
ax.errorbar(range(50),rand(50),yerr=.3*rand(50))
plt.draw()
```

[image: error bar hack]

report as an issue to matploblib https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/1622 (now patched and closed)

Comment: @tcaswell Thank you very much. You've helped me yet again. I had tried setting zorder to be positive, but never considered forcing the underlying plots to be negative. Brilliant.

Comment: @William Glad it helped.  You should really update your mpl though as I think that patch is 1.2.1

Comment: @tcaswell I just encountered what seems to be the same problem in 1.4.2, reproducing your buggy 1.2.0 (?) plot from above. Comment added to the long-closed github ticket...

Comment: This bug is also back in matplotlib 2.0.0. I have created / reopened the ticket. There was also a better "hack" mentioned with `zorder=3` to `plt.errorbar`. I will edit the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

This is a known bug in `matplotlib`. [Link to github issue](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/1622)

**Hacky solution:** Add the argument `zorder=3` when you call `plt.errorbar`, like `plt.errorbar(..., zorder=3)`