# multiple markers in legend

Tags: matplotlib, legend, duplicates

My script for plotting creates two legends for each label. I do not know how to make legend() not duplicate. I checked on stackoverflow and found two methods. But I could not implement them here. Any ideas?

[Matplotlib: Don't show errorbars in legend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14297714/matplotlib-dont-show-errorbars-in-legend)

[Stop matplotlib repeating labels in legend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13588920/stop-matplotlib-repeating-labels-in-legend)

```
symbols = [u'\u2193']
#Plotting our vsini values
for i, symbol in enumerate(symbols):
    for x0,y0 in zip(vsini_slit_cl, vsini_slit):
        plt.text(x0,y0, symbol, fontname='STIXGeneral', size = 10, va='center', ha='center', clip_on=True,color = '#737373')
for i, symbol in enumerate(symbols):
    for x0, y0 in zip(vsini_cl_sl, vsini_sl):
       plt.text(x0, y0, symbol, fontname='STIXGeneral', size = 10, va='center', ha='center', clip_on=True)

# PLOTTING VSINI FROM LITERATURE 
plt.plot((vmag_lit-jmag_lit), vsini_lit, 'o', color = '#a6a6a6', label='Literature')
# PLOTTING SLOW VSINI FROM LITERATURE 
plt.plot(vsini_slit_cl, vsini_slit, 'o', color = '#a6a6a6')
# PLOTTING VSINI FROM OUR WORK
plt.plot(vsini_cl_sl, vsini_sl, 'o', label='This Work' )
plt.errorbar(vsini_color, vsini_chad, yerr=vsini_chad_sig, fmt='bo', capsize=3)
plt.legend()        
plt.savefig('vsini_colors.jpg', dpi=200)
```

[image]

Comment: Can you change the title to something like 'multiple markers in legend'?  The title now makes me think more of the line 'This work' showing up a bunch of times.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use

```
plt.legend(numpoints=1)
```

The default behavior is to use 2 points, which is what you need to make a legend entry for lines.

See: [legend user guide](http://matplotlib.org/users/legend_guide.html) and [`plt.legend` doc](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.legend) and [`legend` doc](http://matplotlib.org/api/legend_api.html#matplotlib.legend.Legend)

Comment: Along these lines, I wanted to know why the "downward arrows" appear in front of the filled circles even when I plot the arrows first and then then filled circles?

Comment: the answer is specify a 'zorder'. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16770049/strange-matplotlib-zorder-behavior-with-legend-and-errorbar

Comment: Thanks for everything and for a quick reply! Very much appreciated. I really like working in Python. Gives you a lot of freedom than IDL.