# Aligning markers for individual points in matplotlib and removing "double" legend for markers in matplotlib in Python

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib, markers

I am trying to figure out the alignment of Markers in "ax.plot" . Apart from plotting 2 bar graphs, I also need to plot 2 points, one per bar graph.
Here's what I am looking for -:

1. **Centering/alignment of markers** ('o' and '*' here, in the center of each bar, rather than at the edge of the bar graph. "o" should come at the center of the 1st bar graph and "*" should come at the center of the 2nd bar graph, their individual heights will differ though, as on the scale "Performance" -the "o" and "*" are "Performance" objects (right hand side scale, as in the figure) - centering, thus means, **overlay of the markers("o" and "***" against its respective stacked graph.
2. **Removing the duplicate marker symbols, with 'o' and '*' in the legend on the upper right corner**. And, understanding why that happens for par2.plot , but not for ax.bar object. Could I have done this without using ax.twinx(), which generates two scales (one for "#candidates"  and other for "Performance" - and if this double entry of legend is related to using the 2 scales ? (I hope not)

   For (2), I also used `plt.legend(numpoints=1) just before the last line, plt,show()` according to the answer here, [multiple markers in legend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16876396/multiple-markers-in-legend) , but that didn't seem to remove the "duplicate markers" in this context.

Also attached is the graph, with (1) and (2) highlighted 
[image]

**Tip -:** Ignore the looping constructs, they are a part of the larger piece, and did not want to change that while pasting, focus on this snippet of the entire code (IMO, this should narrow the problem?)

```
rects1 = ax.bar(ind, Current_Period, width, color=colors)
rects2 = ax.bar(ind+width, Next_Period, width, color='c')
lines_1=par1.plot(perform_1,linestyle='', marker='H', markerfacecolor ='k')
lines_2=par1.plot(perform_2,linestyle='', marker='*',markerfacecolor ='m')
ax.legend((rects1[0], rects2[0],lines_1[0],lines_2[0]), ('Current time period', 'Next time Period','Current Period Performance', 'Next Period Performance'),prop=dict(size=10) )
```

Here is the complete code that I used -:

```
#Final plotting file 
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import rc
#placing anchored text within the figure
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid.anchored_artists import AnchoredText
rc('mathtext', default='regular')

history_P=[[1.4155322812819471, 4.9723842851306213, 3.6831354714462456, 3.0345047089322521, 5.3355879766963819], [2.3240101637275856, 4.7804345245879354, 7.0829471987293973, 6.1050663075245852, 3.6087166298399973], [3.5770722538162265, 3.4516290562530587, 4.4851829512197678, 5.1158026103364733, 3.7873662329909235], [4.7137003352158136, 5.0792119756378593, 4.4624078437179504, 3.1790266221827754, 4.8711126648436895], [4.8043291762010414, 5.6979872315568576, 3.4869780377350339, 3.892755123606721, 3.8142509389863095], [4.8072846135271492, 4.2055137431209033, 5.0441056822018417, 4.1014759291893306, 5.327936039526822]]
history_C=[[14000, 14000, 14000, 14000, 14000], [5373, 18874, 13981, 11519, 20253], [6806, 14001, 20744, 17880, 10569], [12264, 11834, 15377, 17540, 12985], [14793, 15940, 14004, 9977, 15286], [15500, 18384, 11250, 12559, 12307]]

N = 5
ind = np.arange(N)  # the x locations for the groups
width = 0.35

def make_patch_spines_invisible(ax):
    ax.set_frame_on(True)
    ax.patch.set_visible(False)
    for sp in ax.spines.itervalues():
        sp.set_visible(False)

def autolabel(rects):
    # attach some text labels
    for rect in rects:
        height = rect.get_height()
        ax.text(rect.get_x()+rect.get_width()/2., 1.05*height, '%d'%int(height),ha='center', va='bottom')

alphab = ['M1', 'M2', 'M3', 'M4', 'M5', 'M6']

for k in range(0,5):
    colors=[]
    Current_Period=history_C[k]
    Next_Period = history_C[k+1]
    perform_1=history_P[k]
    perform_2=history_P[k+1]

    for i in range(0,5):
        if perform_1[i]==max(perform_1) :
            colors.append('g')
            best=i
        elif perform_1[i]==min(perform_1):
            colors.append('r')
            worst=i
        elif (perform_1[i] != min(perform_1) or perform_1[i] != max(perform_1)):
            colors.append('b')

    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    fig.subplots_adjust(right=0.75)

    par1 = ax.twinx()
    make_patch_spines_invisible(par1)

    rects1 = ax.bar(ind, Current_Period, width, color=colors)
    rects2 = ax.bar(ind+width, Next_Period, width, color='c')
    lines_1=par1.plot(perform_1,linestyle='', marker='H', markerfacecolor ='k')
    lines_2=par1.plot(perform_2,linestyle='', marker='*',markerfacecolor ='m')
    ax.set_xlabel("Model #",style='italic',size='large')
    ax.set_ylabel("Candidate #",style='italic',size='large')
    par1.set_ylabel("Performance",style='italic',size='large')


    ax.set_title('Aggregated Performace Rolled out to candidates, per period',style='italic')
    #fontdict=dict('fontsize':rcParams['axes.titlesize'],'verticalalignment': 'baseline', 'horizontalalignment': loc)
    ax.set_xticks(ind+width)
    ax.set_xticklabels( ('M1', 'M2', 'M3', 'M4', 'M5') )
    ax.annotate('Worst Performer', xy=(worst,0),  xycoords='data',xytext=(-30, 30), textcoords='offset points',size=12, va="center", ha="center",arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="simple", connectionstyle="arc3,rad=-0.2"))
    ax.annotate('Best Performer', xy=(best,0),  xycoords='data',xytext=(-30, 30), textcoords='offset points',size=12, va="center", ha="center",arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="simple", connectionstyle="arc3,rad=-0.2"))
    ax.legend((rects1[0], rects2[0],lines_1[0],lines_2[0]), ('Current time period', 'Next time Period','Current Period Performance', 'Next Period Performance'),prop=dict(size=10) )
    #placing anchored text within the figure, per Period
    at = AnchoredText("Time Period :"+str(k+1),prop=dict(size=10), frameon=True,loc=2,)
    at.patch.set_boxstyle("round,pad=0.,rounding_size=0.2")
    ax.add_artist(at)
    par1.set_ylim(0, 10)

    autolabel(rects1)
    autolabel(rects2)
    plt.show()
```

Comment: in general you should ask exactly one question per question.

Comment: In the meanwhile I also figured out that the easiest way to solve the triple dots in the legend is to use the "scatterpoints=1 " if you are using scatterplots, instead of bar plots  ie. plt.legend((rects[0], rects[0]), ('Current time period', 'Next time Period'),prop=dict(size=10), numpoints=1,scatterpoints=1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You have to provide the [`plot`](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html?highlight=axes#matplotlib.axes.Axes.plot) method with x-coordinate arguments. If given only one list-like object, matplotlib will use this list as the y-coordinates and use `x = np.arange(len(y))` (where `y` are the given y-coordinates).
2. You should not call the [`legend`](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html?highlight=axes#matplotlib.axes.Axes.legend) method several times for each `Axes`; include the `numpoints` kwarg in your original `legend` call.

In other words, replace the lines

```
lines_1=par1.plot(perform_1,linestyle='', marker='H', markerfacecolor ='k')
lines_2=par1.plot(perform_2,linestyle='', marker='*',markerfacecolor ='m')
ax.legend((rects1[0], rects2[0],lines_1[0],lines_2[0]), ('Current time period', 'Next time Period','Current Period Performance', 'Next Period Performance'),prop=dict(size=10) )
```

with

```
lines_1=par1.plot(ind + 0.5*width, perform_1,linestyle='', marker='H', markerfacecolor ='k')
lines_2=par1.plot(ind + 1.5*width, perform_2,linestyle='', marker='*',markerfacecolor ='m')
ax.legend((rects1[0], rects2[0],lines_1[0],lines_2[0]), ('Current time period', 'Next time Period','Current Period Performance', 'Next Period Performance'),prop=dict(size=10), numpoints=1 )
```

This gives the desire output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks @nordev - That was the quickest way to solving, that I was looking for. +1 for not introducing additional cosmetic constructs, and seamlessly fitting in my actual code/solution.

Comment: @ekta `center` is not a 'cosmetic construct' it is part of the api

Answer (score 1):

I think it is slightly better style to use `bar(..., align='center')`, as that is what you really want here:

```
    rects1 = ax.bar(ind, Current_Period, width, color=colors, align='center')
    rects2 = ax.bar(ind+width, Next_Period, width, color='c', align='center')
    lines_1=par1.plot(ind, perform_1,linestyle='', marker='H', markerfacecolor ='k')
    lines_2=par1.plot(ind+width, perform_2,linestyle='', marker='*',markerfacecolor ='m')
    ax.set_xticks(ind + width/2)
    ax.set_xticklabels( ('M1', 'M2', 'M3', 'M4', 'M5') )
    ax.legend((rects1[0], rects2[0],lines_1[0],lines_2[0]), ('Current time period', 'Next time Period','Current Period Performance', 'Next Period Performance'),prop=dict(size=10), numpoints=1 )
```

From a philosophical point of view, it it better to tell the plotting library to do what you want, than to contort your self (and inject details of how the plotting library does things internally) to accommodate the fact that you only are using part of the api.

Comment: You have to specify the x-coords of the second `plot` with `ax.plot(ind + width, perform_2, ...` in order to center these on the second bar.