# matplotlib.legend.set_zorder() doesn't work in ipython notebook

Tags: python, matplotlib

here's a quick thing which is quite annoying me. I've followed the indications found in  [strange matplotlib zorder behavior with legend and errorbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16770049/strange-matplotlib-zorder-behavior-with-legend-and-errorbar) but it doesn't work. Here's a very brief working example

```
x = np.linspace(0,10) 
y = (x-5)**2 
plt.plot(x,y,label='test curve',zorder=100)
plt.legend(loc='center right').set_zorder(102)
```

If you try this you will see that the legend is still underneath the curve, despite the `zorder`ing. Does anyone know why?

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MOekP.png]

I'm using matplotlib 1.3.1 on ipython 3.1.0

Comment: To me it seems that legend and curve are in the right order, but the legend rectangle does not have an opaque background. I tried this with `matplotlib 1.4.3` and the legend is opaque.

Comment: Also tried `matplotlib 1.3.1` and this works as well for me. Maybe a backend issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following on from @cel's comment, I agree you need to add an opaque background to the legend. Try adding:

```
leg=plt.legend(loc='center right')
leg.set_zorder(102)
leg.get_frame().set_facecolor('w')
```

Its also possible to set `legend.facecolor` in your `matplotlibrc` or via `plt.rcParams`

---

Alternatively make sure the `fill` of the legend frame is set to `True`:

```
print leg.get_frame().get_fill()
```

If that prints `False`, try

```
leg.get_frame().set_fill(True)
```

Comment: thank you for the quick answer. I get `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_frame'`

Comment: ah ok. I think you need to set the `zorder` after setting `leg=plt.legend()`. See my edit

Comment: yep, that did the magic. your kung fu is strong tom :) thank you very much